# Tengo problema al verificar un campo insertado en una tabla de una base de datos SQL con un parámetro

Tags: c#, sql-server, datarow, dataset

En la parte del `else` donde dice

```
//Si tiene registros vamos a comparar el parámetro con el campo rfc
```

tengo duda si si se hace así la comparación, la consulta si me trae el los datos bien, y el rfc que trato de ingresar es uno que ya existe en la bd, pero en la comparación del `if (RFC == (DR["rfc"]).ToString())`, parece que no encuentra coincidencias, en que estoy mal, porque no entra a ese if, se vuela al else de más abajo

```
    [HttpGet]
    public Respuesta InsertRazonSocial(string RFC, string Regimen, string Nombre, Guid llaveEmp)
    {
        Respuesta re = new Respuesta();
        try
        {
            if (miConexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                miConexion.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from RazonesSociales where rfc = '" + RFC + "'", miConexion);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "RazonesSociales");
            DataRow DR;
            //var tabla = ds.Tables["RazonesSociales"];
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                //Si está vacía la tabla inserta!
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("insert into RazonesSociales (rfc,nombre,Regimen1,llaveEmp,llave) values (@rfc,@nombre,@Regimen1,@llaveEmp, newid())", miConexion);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfc", RFC);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", Nombre);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regimen1", Regimen);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@llaveEmp", llaveEmp);
                comando.ExecuteReader();
                re.Estatus = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //Si tiene registros  vamos a comparar el parámetro con el campo rfc y si son iguales no inserta
                DR = ds.Tables["RazonesSociales"].Rows[0];
                if (RFC == (DR["rfc"]).ToString())
                {
                    re.Estatus = false;
                    re.Mensaje = "RFC ya registrado.";
                }
                else
                {
                    //Si son diferentes lo inserta
                    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("insert into RazonesSociales (rfc,nombre,Regimen1,llaveEmp,llave) values (@rfc,@nombre,@Regimen1,@llaveEmp, newid())", miConexion);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfc", RFC);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", Nombre);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regimen1", Regimen);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@llaveEmp", llaveEmp);
                    comando.ExecuteReader();
                    re.Estatus = true;
                }
                miConexion.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            re.Error = ex;
            re.Estatus = false;
            miConexion.Close();
        }
        return re;
    }
```

Comment: Intenta con `if(DR["rfc"].ToString().Equals(RFC)) { ... }`

Comment: @Flxtr Acabo de intentar con el .equals, y sigue sin funcionar, no hace la comparación, y el data set si tiene el registro en el renglón 0, ahorita intentaré buscar otra solución, si lo logro, pondré la respuesta.

Comment: Por cierto, tu código es susceltible a SQL Injection, debes evitar el uso de consultas dinámicas.

Comment: Si muchas gracias por el consejo, estoy ya mudando todo a entity framework

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude hacerlo, tu ve que acceder al itemarray del DataRow en la posición 0 y convertirlo a string, para poder hacer la comparación, no tengo idea de porque con el método que tenía antes no funcionó, según yo, estaba correcto

```
                string RFCBD = DR.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                if (RFCBD == RFC)
                {
                    re.Estatus = false;
                    re.Mensaje = "El RFC ingresado, ya fue registrado.";
                }
```